# Can we use pscp to copy files between two windows server?

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am working on a project where I need to copy few compiled files from one windows server to another either through Jenkins or some other method.

Can we use pscp to copy files from one windows server to another?
Is there any way we can use jenkins to copy files from two windows servers?

Answer (score 4):

`pscp` requires the other computer to have a SSH server with SCP support installed. For Windows, several such servers exist. (Bitvise WinSSHd is my own favourite.)

But Windows already has file transfer built in (assuming the firewall allows it). If you are allowed to "share" a temporary folder, you can access it from another computer as `\\computername\sharename`:

```
xcopy tmp\* \\othercomputer\jenkins\tmp\
```